# Evernote PHP SDK not returning any results from API

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, evernote

I am trying to use the Evernote PHP SDK within my Laravel app to pull in some notes. However, I can't get it to display any results.

It's included in my composer.json

`evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php": "dev-master"`

I have successfully authorised my app and got the token with following code, I am using the sandbox and can see my app is successfully authorised..

```
    $oauthHandler = new \Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler($sandbox, false, $china);
    $oauthData  = $oauthHandler->authorize($key, $secret, $callback);

    return redirect()->to($oauthData);
```

The in the callback method:

request()->get('oauth_token');

i've created a few test notebooks with some notes inside.

I now want to pull in the notebooks using the following code:

```
    $client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox);

    $notebooks = $client->listNotebooks();
    dd($notebooks);
```

`$notebooks` is returning an empty array, no errors, nothing.

Part code is taken from their sample snippets.

Comment: Hm, notebooks should never be an empty array. Are you sure you're printing it out correctly? add a try/catch around your listNotebooks calls just to make sure there are no exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Looking a the actual source of [listNotebooks](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Evernote/Client.php#L235), it looks like it swallows exceptions. Try calling [listPersonalNotebooks](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Evernote/Client.php#L235) instead, that should throw exceptions that will give you more information.

Comment: Thanks, it's now throwing an Exception:
 EDAMUserException in UserStore.php line 3202: it doesn't give any codes or message but looks like something to do with the token. I am using the token it returns. very strange.

Comment: Try printing out e->errorCode and e->parameter? Those should provide more info.